# How to remove Splash screen for both iOS and Android in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: mobile, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms and was looking for a way to remove the Splash Screen and have my custom animated splash screen, does anyone have the idea about how to do it? Any help at all would be great!

Thanks

Comment: It is all explained [here](http://www.meritsolutions.com/mobile-development/create-a-custom-xamarin-forms-splash-screen-using-a-layout/)

Answer (score 2):

There is a blog post [here](http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=294) that details how remove the default splash screen and replace this on `iOS`, `Android`, and `WindowsPhone`.

For example on the `Android` example, they are talking about creating a new `Activity`, prior to loading the default `Activity` that will launch the `Xamarin.Forms` App.

Using that approach will most likely also work in all other platforms.  As you can do some platform-specific native animation set, prior to launching your real `Xamarin.Forms` App in your `PCL`.

Comment: link no longer works